# Increasing index value inside .each loop jquery several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, each

I looked at a lot of question regarding this but couldn't find an answer to this .. Sorry if it is basic thing, but I am still learning JS.

I am parsing json data to be fetched onto cards (3 cards in a row), the problem is that the .each loop doesn't save the index value that vas increased inside the loop (3 times increment).. is there any way to store the index value to use it again in the loop with its final state..

Code:

.each loop with shortened code of cards,

```
  $.each(weekno.slice(), function(i, data) {
      var ul_data = [
         '<div class="container">'+
            '<div class="flex-container">'+
              '<div class="card">'+
                    '<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>'+
                         '<div class="card-content">'+
            '<p>Week '+ weekno[i] +'</p>'+
            '<p>Week '+ content[i] +'</p>'+

                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+

             '<div class="card">'+
                    '<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>'+
                         '<div class="card-content">'+
             '<p>Week '+ weekno[i+1] +'</p>'+
                '<p>Week '+ content[i+1] +'</p>'+

                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+              

             '<div class="card">'+
                    '<div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>'+
                         '<div class="card-content">'+
            '<p>Week '+ weekno[i+2] +'</p>'+
              '<p>Week '+ content[i+2] +'</p>'+
                         '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
              '</div>'
            '</div>'+];
$("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);
```

The loop is showing the first 3 cards properly:

```
Card 1: Week No. 1,  Content 1 
Card 2: Week No. 2,  Content 2 
Card 3: Week No. 3, Content 3
```

But then start repeating:

```
Card 4: Week No. 2, Content 2 
Card 5: Week No. 3, Content 3 
Card 6: Week No. 4, Content 4
```

Comment: Can you post the json data?

Comment: the json is parsed from google sheet using $.ajax({
    url:url,
    realtime: true,
    dataType:"jsonp",

Comment: It'll be easier to come up with an answer if I could see at least a section of the json data

Comment: I didn't even post the full code of the cards since its long, but will try to come up with demo data to run

Comment: here is a demo data https://jsfiddle.net/wtydLo3b/1/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) this is perfect for your case.

In the first step you define a html template, which you late combine with a json object to generate your finished html cards.The Html-Template can be placed in your index.html.

**Html-Template**

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="card-template">
         {{#each data}} <!--Defines a loop throw the data passed into the template -->
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/100)"></div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <p>Week {{data.weekno}}</p> <!--Read the weeekno from the passed data-->
                <p>Week {{data.content}}</p><!--Same as above read the content-->
              </div>
          </div>
        {{/each}} <!--Close loop-->
    </script>
```

**index.html**

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flex-container" id="content-placeholder">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var source = $("#card-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var data = {
          "data" : [
            { weekno: 1, content: 'Week 1' },
            { weekno: 1, content: 'Week 1' },
            { weekno: 1, content: 'Week 1' }
          ]
        };
        var html = template(data);
        $("#content-placeholder").html(html);
    </script>
```

I dont know if you are using a framework like Bootstrap or Materilze. Because this would be your other option to take a look at their [Grid-system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Btw this exactly the same things I want with demo data https://jsfiddle.net/wtydLo3b/1/... Its very simple no iteration in css

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the problem:**

> You are unnecessarily repeating the `card` element. That is, you're putting **3** cards in each container. That's why you're getting extra *cards*.

You must've focused on only the 1st round through the loop, that's probably why you had put `i`, `i+1` and `i+2`.

**The solution:**

> 1. Remove the extra `card` elements from `ul_data`.
> 2. Figure out a way to have 3 *cards* in the same line using CSS. You can probably use the 
>    [**CSS Grid System**](https://cssgridgarden.com/).

By the way, brush up your knowledge on [Loops](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complete-guide-to-loops-in-javascript-f5e242921d8c/).

Hope this answer helped!

Comment: Thanks, I am new to programming that's why lol... I thought about finding another ways to make cards in a row... But let's say I want to use the same code... Is there any possible way to change the index value inside the loop several times before looping again?

Comment: I have tried grids, but it seems that it not working with loops .. can u please help with it if possible jsfiddle.net/wtydLo3b/1.